# Knapsack problem - recursive approach with memoization

Tags: python, recursion, time-limit-exceeded, memoization, knapsack-problem

This post is based on the [0-1 Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Definition). I came across this problem in **Assignment #4** of Professor Tim Roughgarden's course *Greedy Algorithms, Minimum Spanning Trees, and Dynamic Programming* on Coursera.

**Question 1:**

> In this programming problem and the next you'll code up the knapsack
>   algorithm from lecture.
>
> Let's start with a warm-up. Download the text file below.
>
> [knapsack.txt](https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/_6dfda29c18c77fd14511ba8964c2e265_knapsack1.txt?Expires=1545696000&Signature=MBY14xIUphAPAB7Yfbk4jsI1uYGSYa3CeqazBVkIJC0KLQ4vSjT8C6MS-BLnay~eS7oVkaspGl70kcCaW2eDfhCVAvmaOTsNiEWJOVV-jkfL~v75E0lKHcf6fr2bEcGJ2-K5JrfY1H6ImlZN3XzTKAMhlEKrDXdp9nJx3WsJFZM_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A)
>
> This file describes a knapsack instance, and it has the following
>   format:
>
> [knapsack_size][number_of_items]
>
> [value_1] [weight_1]
>
> [value_2] [weight_2]
>
> ...
>
> For example, the third line of the file is "50074 659", indicating
>   that the second item has value 50074 and size 659, respectively.
>
> You can assume that all numbers are positive. You should assume that
>   item weights and the knapsack capacity are integers.
>
> In the box below, type in the value of the optimal solution.

**My program:**

```
def knapSack(W , wt , val , n): 

    # Base Case 
    if n == 0 or W == 0 : 
        return 0
    # If weight of the nth item is more than Knapsack of capacity 
    # W, then this item cannot be included in the optimal solution 
    if (wt[n-1] > W): 
        return knapSack(W , wt , val , n-1) 
    # Check for required value in lookup table first
    if (lookup[n][W]!=-1):
        return lookup[n][W]     
    # Add to lookup table and return the maximum of two cases: 
    # (1) nth item included 
    # (2) not included 
    else: 
        x = max(val[n-1] + knapSack(W-wt[n-1] , wt , val , n-1), knapSack(W , wt , val , n-1))
        lookup[n][W] = x
        return x

#End of function knapSack 

#To test above function 
val = []
wt = []
with open("knapsack.txt") as f:
    first_line = f.readline().split()
    W = int(first_line[0])
    n = int(first_line[1])
    for line in f:
      words = line.split()
      val.append(int(words[0]))
      wt.append(int(words[1])) 
lookup = [[-1 for i in range(W+1)] for j in range(n+1)]
print knapSack(W, wt, val, n)
```

This program gave me the output as 2493893, which matches with the official solution. So I presume that my code is correct. So far so good. The next question in the same assignment is as follows.

**Question 2:**

> This problem also asks you to solve a knapsack instance, but a much
>   bigger one.
>
> Download the text file below.
>
> [knapsack_big.txt](https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/_6dfda29c18c77fd14511ba8964c2e265_knapsack_big.txt?Expires=1545696000&Signature=DzUrI7GKCMX-9MUJQo~hweafZElsQdMWF8XlKcKtzTZFSAPCjzOlj5b64usI~6JgEMMRn6p5meFsMKds3QsoNoEadTLd4XCL3w~6w7OkcKqzv5xzkqUSfa68phtWm1uZlJ2PaCV8sWHwGiM3Bxti1AIrHy7GZRzX9nwiGGpG3J0_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A)
>
> This file describes a knapsack instance, and it has the following
>   format:
>
> [knapsack_size][number_of_items]
>
> [value_1] [weight_1]
>
> [value_2] [weight_2]
>
> ...
>
> For example, the third line of the file is "50074 834558", indicating
>   that the second item has value 50074 and size 834558, respectively. As
>   before, you should assume that item weights and the knapsack capacity
>   are integers.
>
> This instance is so big that the straightforward iterative
>   implemetation uses an infeasible amount of time and space. So you will
>   have to be creative to compute an optimal solution. One idea is to go
>   back to a recursive implementation, solving subproblems --- and, of
>   course, caching the results to avoid redundant work --- only on an "as
>   needed" basis. Also, be sure to think about appropriate data
>   structures for storing and looking up solutions to subproblems.
>
> In the box below, type in the value of the optimal solution.

**My program (same as before):**

```
def knapSack(W , wt , val , n): 

    # Base Case 
    if n == 0 or W == 0 : 
        return 0
    # If weight of the nth item is more than Knapsack of capacity 
    # W, then this item cannot be included in the optimal solution 
    if (wt[n-1] > W): 
        return knapSack(W , wt , val , n-1) 
    # Check for required value in lookup table first
    if (lookup[n][W]!=-1):
        return lookup[n][W]     
    # Add to lookup table and return the maximum of two cases: 
    # (1) nth item included 
    # (2) not included 
    else: 
        x = max(val[n-1] + knapSack(W-wt[n-1] , wt , val , n-1), knapSack(W , wt , val , n-1))
        lookup[n][W] = x
        return x

#End of function knapSack 

#To test above function 
val = []
wt = []
with open("knapsack_big.txt") as f:
    first_line = f.readline().split()
    W = int(first_line[0])
    n = int(first_line[1])
    for line in f:
      words = line.split()
      val.append(int(words[0]))
      wt.append(int(words[1])) 
lookup = [[-1 for i in range(W+1)] for j in range(n+1)]
print knapSack(W, wt, val, n)
```

The second question had mentioned that the ordinary iterative approach would not suffice and that we'd have to get back to the recursive approach and use appropriate caching. Fair enough. I had already used the recursive approach in my initial program and also implemented a lookup table for [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) purposes.

It worked perfectly fine on the smaller data set i.e. `knapsack.txt` and took less than a second to execute. However, when I execute the program on the second file `knapsack_big.txt` (which is considerably larger than `knapsack.txt`) it takes forever to execute and in most cases ends up getting [killed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189522/what-does-killed-mean).

So, any idea how to speed up the program so that it can be executed on larger data sets? I suspect that there might be more efficient data structures (than a simple 2D list) for this problem, but not sure which.

Comment: I'd propose that, for posterity, you also include in-text the contents of `knapsack.txt` as it's relatively short.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: For your speed-up problem, have you tried what happened if, instead of keeping a list `val` and `wt`, you keep a list of tuples containing `(val, wt)`? It appears you only use them for same-index values, so it might be faster on both the append and the look-up.

Comment: @Mast Thanks, I will try that out but not sure if that will be a substantial improvement.

Comment: Neither am I, hence a comment instead of an answer, but I'd say it's worth a try. Something even more important you should try, is [profiling your code](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5284/52915) to see where the bottlenecks are. It takes some getting used to, but being able to profile is an essential skill in debugging performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def knapSack(W , wt , val , n):
```

This is not PEP8-compliant. You should run this code through a linter. For that particular line, it would instead be

```
def knapsack(W, wt, val, n):
```

You have several lines like this:

```
if (wt[n-1] > W):
```

with parens around the `if` condition. These parens are not needed.

This:

```
print knapSack(W, wt, val, n)
```

uses Python 2-style `print`. In most cases, using Python 3-style `print` is compatible with Python 2, and this is such a case; so for forward compatibility you should instead write

```
print(knapSack(W, wt, val, n))
```

This:

```
if (lookup[n][W]!=-1):
    return lookup[n][W]     
else:
```

doesn't need the `else`, since the previous block would have already returned.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This doesn’t address the speedup issue though (which is the main problem I’m facing).

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an answer but more of an [update](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765). I ran the code through a linter - [Pylint](https://www.pylint.org/), as suggested by [@Reinderien](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/210253/188780). These are the current versions:

---

```
'''Programming Assignment #4: Question 1'''
def knapsack(max_weight, weights, values, max_value):
    '''Recursive method for the knapsack problem (with memoization)'''
    # Base Case
    if max_value == 0 or max_weight == 0:
        return 0
    # If weight of the nth item is more than Knapsack of capacity
    # W, then this item cannot be included in the optimal solution
    if weights[max_value-1] > max_weight:
        return knapsack(max_weight, weights, values, max_value-1)
    # Check for required value in lookup table first
    if LOOKUP[max_value][max_weight] != -1:
        return LOOKUP[max_value][max_weight]
    # Add to lookup table and return the maximum of two cases:
    # (1) nth item included
    # (2) not included
    val1 = knapsack(max_weight-WEIGHTS[max_value-1], weights, values, max_value-1)
    val1 += VALUES[max_value-1]
    # val1 stores the maximum possible profit when the last item is included
    val2 = knapsack(max_weight, weights, values, max_value-1)
    # val2 stores the maximum possible profit when the last item is excluded
    temp = max(val1, val2)
    LOOKUP[max_value][max_weight] = temp
    return temp
#End of function knapsack
#To test above function
VALUES = []
WEIGHTS = []
#Reading the data file
with open("knapsack.txt") as f:
    FIRST_LINE = f.readline().split()
    MAX_WEIGHT = int(FIRST_LINE[0])
    MAX_VALUE = int(FIRST_LINE[1])
    for line in f:
        words = line.split()
        VALUES.append(int(words[0]))
        WEIGHTS.append(int(words[1]))
#Declaring and initializing the lookup table
LOOKUP = [[-1 for i in range(MAX_WEIGHT+1)] for j in range(MAX_VALUE+1)]
#Function knapsack is invoked
print knapsack(MAX_WEIGHT, WEIGHTS, VALUES, MAX_VALUE)
```

---

```
'''Programming Assignment #4: Question 2'''
def knapsack(max_weight, weights, values, max_value):
    '''Recursive method for the knapsack problem (with memoization)'''
    # Base Case
    if max_value == 0 or max_weight == 0:
        return 0
    # If weight of the nth item is more than Knapsack of capacity
    # W, then this item cannot be included in the optimal solution
    if weights[max_value-1] > max_weight:
        return knapsack(max_weight, weights, values, max_value-1)
    # Check for required value in lookup table first
    if LOOKUP[max_value][max_weight] != -1:
        return LOOKUP[max_value][max_weight]
    # Add to lookup table and return the maximum of two cases:
    # (1) nth item included
    # (2) not included
    val1 = knapsack(max_weight-WEIGHTS[max_value-1], weights, values, max_value-1)
    val1 += VALUES[max_value-1]
    # val1 stores the maximum possible profit when the last item is included
    val2 = knapsack(max_weight, weights, values, max_value-1)
    # val2 stores the maximum possible profit when the last item is excluded
    temp = max(val1, val2)
    LOOKUP[max_value][max_weight] = temp
    return temp
#End of function knapsack
#To test above function
VALUES = []
WEIGHTS = []
#Reading the data file
with open("knapsack_big.txt") as f:
    FIRST_LINE = f.readline().split()
    MAX_WEIGHT = int(FIRST_LINE[0])
    MAX_VALUE = int(FIRST_LINE[1])
    for line in f:
        words = line.split()
        VALUES.append(int(words[0]))
        WEIGHTS.append(int(words[1]))
#Declaring and initializing the lookup table
LOOKUP = [[-1 for i in range(MAX_WEIGHT+1)] for j in range(MAX_VALUE+1)]
#Function knapsack is invoked
print knapsack(MAX_WEIGHT, WEIGHTS, VALUES, MAX_VALUE)
```

---

The above programs should be fine syntactically now. They returned a 10/10 score on being run through Pylint. However, as mentioned in the original question, the code still gets killed whenever it is executed on large data files like `knapsack_big.txt`.

Comment: Typically capitalized values are only seen on globals. I think the reason they appear in your program is that you have a bunch of global code. You should attempt to put all of your global-scope code into a `main` function; then pylint will probably change its suggestions to de-capitalize those variables.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the question is still relevant. But this line is creating a list that is too big that exceeds most memory limits:

> ```
> LOOKUP = [[-1 for i in range(MAX_WEIGHT+1)] for j in range(MAX_VALUE+1)]
> ```

Instead of creating the `LOOKUP` table upfront, it may be better to save the sub-problems in a hash table or a search tree as you solve them.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Is this an observation about the code in [the answer by JD](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/210262/120114)? The main objective is to review the OPs code.